# Why does if($x = 1 && $x == 1) throw error but if ($x == 1 && $x = 2) doesn't in php?

Tags: php, operators

In php the following code gives a warning of *undefined variable $x*:

`if($x = 1 && $x == 1)`

I thought it was equivalent to `if( ($x = 1) && ($x == 1) )`, but that's not the case. I've been told, it's because `&&` has higher precedence than `=`, which causes the expression to get converted to:

`if($x = (1 && ($x == 1)))`

So far so good, but now consider:

`$x=1; if($x == 1 && $x = 2)`

This doesn't throw error. Why doesn't it get converted to:
`$x=1; if(  (($x == 1) && $x) = 2  )`

I've been told thats due to `=` being right assosiative, but https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php says *When operators have equal precedence their associativity decides how the operators are grouped.*. Here we have `=`, `&&` and `==` all being of different precedence.

P.S; My actual code is `if($result != false && $res = $stmt->get_result())`, which has been copied from some other reputable source, so seems like not using unneeded parenthesis is common in php.

Comment: What do you mean with "code throws error"? I see only a notice with this code `if($x = 1 && $x == 1)`

Comment: @Slava I get a warning, `Undefined variable $x in ... ... on line 14`. I've edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Okay, thanks. What I see that if you set $x before if() then both conditions do not throw a notice. If you do not set $x before if() then `both` cases throw a notice: `if ($x = 1 && $x == 1)` and `if($x == 1 && $x = 2)` (PHP 7.4)

Comment: @Slava My true question is whats the order of execution by php in my second example which doesn't throw error. The first example won't throw error with `$x = 1`, but doesn't make the if statement true: `$x = 1;  
 if($x = 2 && $x == 2) {  
  echo "$x";  
 }`

Comment: Now I've got you, but your inital question is actually about throwing errors)

Comment: The $x on the right side here is not defined yet, this the notice: if($x = (1 && ($x == 1)))

Answer (score 0):

I've played with several conditions and below is what I've got.

First, let's consider that we init `$x` before `if` statements to avoid undefined variable notice.

Second, let's confirm the [precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) for operators:

1. `==` is applied 1st
2. `&&` is applied 2nd
3. `=` is applied 3rd

---

This returns `true`:

```
$x = 1;
if ($x = 1 && $x == 1) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

It goes like `($x = (1 && ($x == 1)))` -> `($x = (1 && true))` -> `($x = true)` -> `true`.

---

If we compare `$x` to another value than the assigned one we will get `false`:

```
$x = 1;
if ($x = 2 && $x == 2) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

It goes like `($x = (2 && ($x == 2)))` -> `($x = (2 && false))` -> `($x = false)` -> `false`.

---

The last one returns `true`:

```
$x = 1;
if ($x == 1 && $x = 2) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

It goes like `((($x == 1) && $x) = 2)` -> `((true && $x) = 2)` -> `(true = 2)` -> `true`.

The last comparison can't be interpreted by PHP so it's an approximate view.

It looks like the last action `(true = 2)` totally **depends on the left operand**. If we put `$x = 2;` we will get `(false = 2)` -> `false`.

---

I'm not sure about the last one and here is the only place were some mistakes can happen.

Otherwise, it looks like precedence works as expected.

Anyway, I always put parenthesis for an assignment action inside `if` operator (especially inside ternary if) to be sure that I will get what I expect.
I don't think this affects performance or readability too much, but it may prevent some logical errors.

---

**UPDATE**:

Concering your code `if($result != false && $res = $stmt->get_result())` it's not correct to compare it to `if($x == 1 && $x = 2)` because in your code are two different variables.

In this case logical operator will not call the second part at all if the fisrt one is `false`, see the 1st example [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

**UPDATE-2**:

After the discussion under this answer we can see that the last conditions `($x == 1 && $x = 2)` work like like `(($x == 1) && ($x = 2))` -> `((1 == 1) && 2)` -> `true` and `$x` becomes 2 after it.

Comment: Consider another example: `$x = 1;
if ($x == 1 && $x = 2) {
    echo "first" . $x;
} else {
    echo $x;
}`  It means `$x = 2` is being executed first.

Comment: About the last example you are right it looks like `(($x == 1) && ($x = 2))`. Perhaps, it's due to impossibility to parse something like this `(true = 2)`

Comment: Lets delete all unnecessary comments. In my actual code I also have `if( $result != false && ($result = $stmt->get_result()) && ($result->num_rows > 0) )` Here I was forced to use parenthesis around `$result->num_rows > 0`. Since `!=` has same precedence as `==`, something like `if($x==1 && $y=2)` and `if($x!=1 && $y=2)` -- should they end being executed in same order?

Comment: as far as we discussed before if the left condition == false then the right condition will be skipped at all and your `$y` will be left undefined